# Name for finite partial order sets

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Is-there a name for the (finite) partially ordered sets (posets) which have no "commutative square" in their Hasse diagram ? In other words, finite posets in which all the intervals are (possibly empty) chains ?

This does not imply that the Hasse diagram of the poset is a tree. For example the poset $({1,2,3,4},\leq)$ with $1\leq 2$, $1\leq 3$, $4\leq 2$ and $4\leq 3$ has this property.

Comment: Have you looked in Birkhoff's book?

Comment: Seems a bit like a multirooted tree of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to be called *diamond-free* posets (see [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00631v1.pdf) e.g.);  Google the term and you'll find many counting problems related to it. Also (if we consider the Hasse diagram as an ordered graph) [multitree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree) seems to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much!